# Need to Concat strings in C# windows

Tags: c#

In a list, I'm having some string values based on certain condition.
I need to concatenate the string value with another string `"SUM()"`.

For eg:List contains values `A1`, `A2`, `A3`

The output string should be

> Sum(A1)  as A1,Sum(A2) as A2,Sum(A3) as A3

My code is as follows:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    strList .Add(dr[0].ToString());
}
string NewStrSum  = "";
string NewColSum = "";
NewStrSum = "  SUM(";
NewColSum = NewStrSum + String.Join(") ", strList .Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
```

But the output is Sum(A1)A2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = new List<string> {"A1", "A2", "A3"};
var str = list.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, item) => current + string.Format("SUM({0}) AS {0},", item));
str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that last statement is really ugly. Isn't this what `string.Join` is for?

Comment: You are right, it's not the prettiest line but it's has better performance when there are many elements, than creating new element in the requested format, if i didn't had to re-format it i would use the join function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) to get every element in your `List<string>` with specified formatted and use it with [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to concatenate them with `,` as;

```
var list = new List<string>() {"A1", "A2", "A3"};
var newlist = list.Select(s => string.Format("SUM({0}) as {0}", s));
var result = string.Join(",", newlist);
```

`result` will be;

```
SUM(A1) as A1,SUM(A2) as A2,SUM(A3) as A3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
// Create your list
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("A1");
list.Add("A2");
list.Add("A3");

// Create list of elements that look like 'Sum(X) as X':
var sumList = list.Select(x=>string.Format("Sum({0}) as {0}", x));

// Create single string
var result = string.Join(", ", sumList);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = string.Empty;

for(int i=0;i<strList.Count;i++)
{
    if(i!=0)
    result+= " , ";
    result+= "Sum("+strList[i]+") as "+strList[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to concat the strings inside the bucle foreach

here an example:

```
string OutPut  = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    OutPut += "SUM("
                            + dr[0].ToString()
                            + ") as ";
                            + dr[0].ToString()
                            +", "; 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below,

```
// This is your code
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    strList .Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }

// New Code
string newColSum = string.Join(",", strList.Select(s => string.Format("SUM({0}) as {0}", s)));
```